# Access frame inside frameset that is inside another frameset

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How do I access a frame that's present inside a frameset which is inside another frameset?

[image]

Here's my code which returns `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchFrameException: Message: no such frame`.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://netbanking.hdfcbank.com/netbanking/")
driver.switch_to_default_content()

assert "Welcome to HDFC Bank" in driver.title

driver.switch_to_frame("login_page")

try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(driver.find_element_by_class_name('pwd_field')))
    print "Page is ready!"
except TimeoutException:
    print "Loading took too much time!"

driver.implicitly_wait(10)  # seconds
driver.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to handle `frameset`s in any special way - these are just containers for the frames, they are not frames themselves. Here is what worked for me:

- add a wait to wait for the frame to be present
- switch to the frame

The code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://netbanking.hdfcbank.com/netbanking/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

assert "Welcome to HDFC Bank" in driver.title

frame = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'login_page')))
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)

try:
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'pwd_field')))
    print("Page is ready!")
except TimeoutException:
    print("Loading took too much time!")

driver.close()
```

---

Note that I've also fixed the wait you've already had, replaced:

```
.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(driver.find_element_by_class_name('pwd_field')))
```

with:

```
.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'pwd_field')))
```

I've also removed the first `driver.switch_to_default_content()` call - you are already operating in the scope of the default content at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there a cleaner way to wait for the required "element" rather than just waiting for 10 seconds?

Comment: @AbhijeetRastogi sure, do you mean the `wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'pwd_field')))` part? This would wait **up to** 10 seconds (10 is what we've initialized the `WebDriverWait` in this case) and is the most recommended way to wait for an element or any specific condition to be satisfied..

Comment: Thanks @alecxe. You're awesome. This is my first time trying out selenium.